# Openseadragon, DeepZoom, WordPress

Tags: wordpress, deepzoom, openseadragon

Trying to setup [OpenSeadragon](https://openseadragon.github.io/) for a WordPress site.  Just testing around now and trying to get the zoom feature to work.

- I've included the [OpenSeadragon](https://openseadragon.github.io/) scripts in order to view the DZI images.  I tink I'm good there.
- My issue is actually generating a DZI image from a hi-res image.  How do I do this and can it be done on the fly?

I've tried including the [DeepZoom](https://github.com/jeremytubbs/deepzoom) tile generator without success and continue getting a "*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'League\Flysystem\Filesystem' not found*" error.

The only other DZI generator I see that might work is a Windows desktop app which won't work, I'm on a mac.

This is what I have so far (just working of examples provided by openseadragon and deepzoom):

I'm including Deepzoom.php and DeepzoomFactory.php in my functions file.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area zoom">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

    <?php
    // Setup Deepzoom
    $deepzoom = Jeremytubbs\Deepzoom\DeepzoomFactory::create([
        'path' => '/wp-content/uploads/DZI/ready/', // Export path for tiles
        'driver' => 'imagick', // Choose between gd and imagick support.
        'format' => 'jpg',
    ]);
    // folder, file are optional and will default to filename
    $response = $deepzoom->makeTiles('/wp-content/uploads/DZI/oklahoma.jpg');
    ?>

    <div id="openseadragon1" style="width: 800px; height: 600px;"></div>
    <script src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ; ?>/lib/openseadragon/openseadragon.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
            id: "openseadragon1",
            prefixUrl: "/wp-content/themes/truelook/lib/openseadragon/images/",
            tileSources: <?php echo $response; ?>
        });
    </script>
```

Any suggestions or advice pointing me in the right directio would be most welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) has `dzsave`, which can make deepzoom pyramids of any size very quickly. There's a [chapter in the docs](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/API/current/Making-image-pyramids.md.html) about it.

You can install on a mac with [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), macports, fink etc. For example:

```
brew install vips
```

Then make the pyramid with:

```
vips dzsave oklahoma.jpg x
```

and it'll create `x_files` and `x.dzi` (use a different name, of course).

You can also use [php-vips](https://github.com/libvips/php-vips) (the PHP binding for libvips) to create pyramids. Something like:

```
$im = Vips\Image::newFromFile('oklahoma.jpg', 
    ['access' => Vips\Access::SEQUENTIAL]);
$im->dzsave('x');
```

It might be fast enough for on-the-fly generation, it depends on the image size, format and your requirements. On this 2015 laptop with a 10k x 10k pixel RGB image I see:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e vips dzsave wtc.jpg x
98856:3.93
```

So 100mb of memory and 4s of elapsed time.

Answer (score 0):

have you seen this Zoom OpenSeadragon [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/zoom-openseadragon/) ?
it outdated but it might help you make the backed operation smoother.

Answer (score 0):

To make the deepzoom run, you should install dependencies with composer.
First clone the deepzoom repository. Get into repo dir and run `php composer install` command. [Composer Docs to install dependencies](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#installing-dependencies)
After the isntallation completed, add this line above your codes:

```
require 'deepzoom/vendor/autoload.php';
```

**Note** that you should use absolute path for 'path' and filename parameters.
Example:

```
$deepzoom = Jeremytubbs\Deepzoom\DeepzoomFactory::create([
    'path' => '/home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads/DZI', // Export path for tiles. Do not add / end of path
    'driver' => 'imagick', // Choose between gd and imagick support.
    'format' => 'jpg',
]);

$response = $deepzoom->makeTiles('/home/username/public_html/wp-content/uploads/2020/1/image.jpg');
```

Do not include this code in your template file. Create another .php file and pass the file name.